# tengo mi proyecto React.js ya funcionando perfectamente (en local) y listo para subir, pero tengo un problema con las rutas, esta es mi app:

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
      <Router>
    <Header />
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Inicio />} />
        <Route path="/preparacionIntegral" exact element={<PreparacionIntegralPage />} />
        <Route path="/clasePersonalizada" exact element={<ClasePersonalizada />} />
        <Route path="/MasterClass" exact element={<MasterClass />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

1. 

### Elemento de lista

En Localhost esas rutas funcionan y se ven correctamente.
Están colocados en el en Navbar. Al correr npm run build me crea la app lista para subirla al hosting,subo al hosting y se ve perfectamente la pagina principal, pero al hacer click en Master class , Clase Personalizada y Preparacion integral, indica que no existe esa ruta y no se puede ver. Que podria ser? el hosting es hostinger.

Logro darme cuenta que cuando reviso el proyecto subido a hostinger no me figuran las rutas.

Gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

El estándar es que la ruta en una URL distinga entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

```
<Router>
  <Header />
  <div>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" exact element={<Inicio />} />
      <Route path="/preparacion-integral" exact element={<PreparacionIntegralPage />} />
      <Route path="/clase-personalizada" exact element={<ClasePersonalizada />} />
      <Route path="/master-class" exact element={<MasterClass />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
</Router>
```